# rails controller instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I’m trying to show a list of employee alerts for each supervisor.

I have an Alerts controller with 2 instance variables that are both working.

```
@alerts  = contains all alerts (alert.id | employee_id)    
@employees = contains the employees for each supervisor (current_user | employee_id’s)
```

I’m trying to get something like `@supervisor_alerts`, that will show the alerts only for the current supervisor.

```
@supervisor_alerts = @alerts.where(@alerts(:employee_id) 
 = @employees(:employee_id))
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please format your code and provide the associations between employee, supervisors, and alerts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try with this 
    @supervisor_alerts = @alerts.where(employee_id: employee_id’s)